# Subscribe Angular 6

Tags: arrays, angular, typescript, subscribe

```
toppings : Array
toppings2 : Array
```

I have 2 subscribe methods :

```
this.toppings.valueChanges.subscribe(val=> { 
console.log(val);
}

this.toppings2.valueChanges.subscribe(val2=> { 
console.log(val2);
}
```

I want to use val and val2 in the same fonction . How i can obtain val and val2 in a same place ? (or val3= val+val2)

Comment: you can use zip function https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/combination/zip.html `zip(this.toppings.valueChanges, this.toppings2.valueChanges).subscribe(val => console.log(val[0] + val[1]))`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**[`zip`](http://rxmarbles.com/#zip)** combines two observables and waits for both of them to emit. combineLatest will do as well, it doesn't really matter 
you need,

```
zip(this.toppings.valueChanges, this.toppings2.valueChanges).subscribe(val => console.log(val[0] + val[1]))
```

Comment: I mus import { Observable,zip } from 'rxjs';?

Comment: sorrymaouseclik

Comment: i can't listen my console.log(val[0] + val[1]) they are a problem if toppings provide from a form ?

Answer (score 4):

combineLatest will give you the latest version of both toppings and toppings2.

https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/combination/combinelatest.html

Marble diagram: http://rxmarbles.com/#combineLatest

Example:

```
import {combineLatest} from 'rxjs';

combineLatest(this.toppings.valueChanges, this.toppings2.valueChanges )
                          .subscribe( ([topping1val, topping2val]) => {
                                      let topping3 = topping1val + topping2val;
                                 });
```